# Why does jQuery html() fail when run within my webpage in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

This is the code extracted out of my page:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nt7V9/4/

What it is trying to do is convert the WellName values into links based on the content of other cells in the same row.

It works fine in IE10 in jsFiddle, but in the actual application it fails within the .html() call. Error "Object doesn't support this property or method" on IE 10. Other browsers work fine.

```
cells.eq(wellNameColumnIndex).html(('<a href="' + link + '" target="_blank">' + wellName + '</a>'));

Stack trace:
    clean, jquery-1.7.2.min.js, line 4
    buildFragment, jquery-1.7.2.min.js, line 4
    domManip, jquery-1.7.2.min.js, line 4
    append, jquery-1.7.2.min.js, line 3
    Anonymous function, jquery-1.7.2.min.js, line 4
    access, jquery-1.7.2.min.js, line 2
    html, jquery-1.7.2.min.js, line 4
    Anonymous function, cntrl.table.js, line 104
```

Within *clean* it is stuck at p.**innerHTML**=n[1]+l+n[2]. Inspecting p in the debugger reveals it does not have *innerHTML*. p appears to be an object with property *baseName* "div", but there are no div tags in the input string. Hmm...

Replacing .html with .text works but the cell value is no longer a link but the actual  tag. Also changing to .html("anytext") also fails with the same error.

Can anyone help figure out this mystery?

Comment: Just a notice : jQuery 1.7 wasn't tested for this new browser. Any reason you don't upgrade ?

Comment: If it works fine on jsfiddle, there is probably something else on the live page interfering with it. Duplicate IDs maybe? Extra comma somewhere?

Comment: You can also replace `.html(('' + wellName + ''));` with `.html(wellName);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.html()` in IE requires that the HTML you use as the parameter is *perfectly* formed. It doesn't tolerate any mistakes (Where as Chrome and Firefox will try and clean it up).

Make sure that the HTML you're putting is valid for the doctype you're using.

```
$("#selector").html("<p>Hello World!</p>"); //works

$("#selector").html("<span>Derp</div>"); //does not work
```

Comment: As shown in jsFiddle the html input seems well formed. It is a table string. It is exactly this code.